# Calculate $\int\left( \sqrt{\tan x}+\sqrt{\cot x}\right)dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

How to calculate following integration?

$$\int\left( \sqrt{\tan x}+\sqrt{\cot x}\right)dx$$

Comment: When you write out function names like that, $\TeX$ interprets them as juxtaposed variable names and formats them accordingly. To get the right font and spacing, you can use predefined commands such as `\tan` and `\cot`. If you need a function for which there's no predefined command, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Comment: ok sure thank you so much

Comment: I voted to reopen this question as the [duplicate target](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100253/which-is-the-easiest-way-to-evaluate-int-limits-0-pi-2-sqrt-tan-x) is a definite integral, which might allow for some approaches not available for the indefinite integral.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$I=\int\left( \sqrt{\tan x}+\sqrt{\cot x}\right)dx$$

$$=\int \frac{\sin x+\cos x}{\sqrt{\sin x\cos x}} dx$$

Putting $\sin x-\cos x=u,$
$du=(\cos x+\sin x)dx, u^2=1-2\sin x\cos x,\sin x\cos x=\frac{u^2-1}2$

$$I=\int \frac{\sqrt 2du }{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=\sqrt 2\arcsin u+C=\sqrt 2\arcsin(\sin x-\cos x)+C$$ where $C$ is an arbitrary constant for  indefinite integral.

Comment: @CuriousSciDude, $$\sqrt{\tan x}=\dfrac{\sqrt{\sin x}}{\sqrt{\cos x}}$$

Answer (score 5):

Substitute $\tan x= t^2$
$$\int \sqrt{\tan x}+\sqrt{\cot x} dx=2\int\dfrac{t^2+1}{t^4+1}dt=2\int\dfrac{1+\frac{1}{t^2}}{(t-\frac1{t})^2+2} dt$$ Now make a $t-\frac{1}{t}$ substitution and we get the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately not - $d(t+1/t) \neq (1+1/t^2)dt$.

Comment: @GlenO its now corrected.

Answer (score 5):

Substitute $\tan(x)=u=e^{2t}$:
$$
\begin{align}
\int\left(\sqrt{\tan(x)}+\sqrt{\cot(x)}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int\left(u^{1/2}+u^{-1/2}\right)\,\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1+u^2}\\
&=\int\frac{u^{1/2}+u^{-1/2}}{u+u^{-1}}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u}\\
&=\int\frac{\cosh(t)}{\cosh(2t)}2\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int\frac2{\cosh(2t)}\mathrm{d}\sinh(t)\\
&=\int\frac{\sqrt2}{1+2\sinh^2(t)}\mathrm{d}\sqrt2\sinh(t)\\
&=\sqrt2\arctan(\sqrt2\sinh(t))+C\\
&=\sqrt2\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{\tan(x)}-\sqrt{\cot(x)}}{\sqrt2}\right)+C
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 4):

Let $u=\tan{x}$; the integral becomes

$$\int \frac{du}{1+u^2} \left (\sqrt{u} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}\right)$$

Now let $u=v^2$ and get for the integral on the right

$$\frac{du}{1+u^2} \left (\sqrt{u} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}\right) = 2 \int dv \frac{1+v^2}{1+v^4}$$

which may be evaluated via partial fractions:

$$\begin{align}2 \int dv \frac{1+v^2}{1+v^4} &=  \int dv \left (\frac{1}{v^2-\sqrt{2} v+1} + \frac{1}{v^2+\sqrt{2} v+1} \right )\\ &=  \int dv \left (\frac{1}{(v-1/\sqrt{2})^2+1/2} + \frac{1}{(v+1/\sqrt{2})^2+1/2} \right)\end{align}$$

From here, you can use the standard integral

$$\int \frac{dy}{y^2+a^2} = \frac{1}{a} \arctan{\frac{y}{a}}$$

The intermediate result is

$$\begin{align}2\int dv \frac{1+v^2}{1+v^4} &=  \sqrt{2} \arctan{\frac{1-v^2}{\sqrt{2}v}} = \sqrt{2} \arctan{\frac{1- u}{\sqrt{2u}}} \end{align}$$

Put this altogether to get finally:

$$\int dx \: (\sqrt{\tan{x}} + \sqrt{\cot{x}})= \sqrt{2} \arctan{\left(\frac{1-\tan{x}}{\sqrt{2\tan{x}}}\right)}+C$$

where $C$ is a constant of integration.  You may check this result by taking its derivative.

Comment: Can u explain how u got that intermediate result?

Comment: @VishnuJK: $$dv \frac{1+v^2}{1+v^4} = dv \left ( 1+\frac1{v^2} \right ) \frac{v^2}{1+v^4}\\ = d \left ( v-\frac1{v} \right ) \frac1{v^2+\frac1{v^2}} = d \left ( v-\frac1{v} \right ) \frac1{2+\left (v-\frac1{v} \right )^2} $$

Comment: Ok there are 2 terms after partial fraction but later when we apply the formula there are 2 terms but in this there is not so i kindda confused...

Comment: @RonGordon it'd be helpful to mention how u applied partial fractions as the power of the denominator is 4.