# $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\sqrt{\tan x}+\sqrt{\cot x})\mathrm dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\sqrt{\tan x}+\sqrt{\cot x})\mathrm dx $$
my attempt :multiply and divide the $\sqrt{\tan(x)}$ term by $\sec^2(x)$ and similarly the $\sqrt{\cot(x)}$ by $\csc^2(x)$
and say $\tan x=u^2$ and $\cot x=y^2$
so we get
$$\int_0^\frac{{\pi}}{2} (\frac{2u^2}{1+u^4}\mathrm du- \frac{2y^2}{1+y^4}\mathrm dy)$$

which is $0$.

and that is obviously wrong
I have seen [this answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/338597/879009) that effectively uses the same sub I did , but in a different way. Hence the question.

> What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $u$ and $y$ are not independent. If $\tan(x) = u^2$, then $\cot(x) = u^{-2}$.

Comment: Note that $\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\tan x}\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\cot x}\,\mathrm dx$.

Comment: @sudeep5221,so ths 2nd integral should be $\frac{1+y^4}{2y^2}$?

Comment: One integral sign is missing.

Comment: @MarianG., how is that?

Comment: @ACB, I clubed both under one single integral sign

Comment: I'll revert it. Sorry

Comment: I feel both answers are just as good as the other. Is it fine if I don't select any.? I have upvoted both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\sqrt{\tan x}+\sqrt{\cot x})\mathrm dx=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{2u^2}{1+u^4}\mathrm du+\int_{+\infty}^0\frac{-2y^2}{1+y^4}\mathrm dy.$$

Answer (score 1):

I have three remarks:

1. The upper integral limit, $\pi/2$, would change to $+\infty$ with the $tan(x)=u^2$ transform.
2. You can't write the two fractions with different differentials under the same integral.
3. The $\cot(x)=y^2$ transform would change the limits to $[+\infty, 0]$ which, would account for your lost sign.